# Clever way to handle operating system specific action? (Windowsl/Linux)

Tags: c#, linux, refactoring, cross-platform, .net-6.0

I'm currently developing my first cross-plattform application in .NET6, which should run on windows and linux. I reached the point where I'm having a first stable and working project. Now I wan't to do some refactoring, especially for the parts, where the code is making some operating system specfic actions. At the moment a solved this with a simple if/else like

```
if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux())
{
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
}
else
{
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
}
```

I'm looking for a good way to avoid these if/else statements and create some "cleaner" code. My idea is to have a class like OSSpecificActions and create one function for every usecase.
Like:

```
public class OperatingSystemSpecificAction
{
internal static string PathToDefaultFolder()
    {
        string path = String.Empty;

        if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux())
        {

            path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        }
        else
        {
            path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

and simply call it in my code like this:

```
path = OperatingSystemSpecificAction.PathToDefaultFolder();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DI container to setup the correct versions of the dependencies and then just inject them into the rest of your application,

e.g. in startup:

```
if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux()) 
{
    services.AddTransient<IPathResolver, LinuxPathResolver>();
}
else 
{
    services.AddTransient<IPathResolver, WindowsPathResolver>();
}
```

Then in your consuming class:

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
    public ConsumingClass(IPathResolver pathResolver)
    {
       var correctPath = pathResolver.GetFolderPath()
    }
}
```

The two implementations of the class would do the OS specific logic. This scales better than creating one big class full of "OS specific actions".